# Where is the man page for the format specifiers in the C function printf?

Tags: c, linux, manpage

I cannot find the section for format specifiers in the C `printf` function. I've done a `man printf` on my Linux distro and it doesn't provide that information.

So far, I've just been googling everytime I need to find out a format. I'm sure that this question has been asked before on stackoverflow, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Are you looking at the man page for the printf command or the function?  They're definitely in the function's man page, at least on my system.

Comment: Do `man 3 printf` to get the man page for the C function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unix manual is divided into sections. The following are the first three:

1. Command-line utilities (e.g. `bash`)
2. System calls (e.g. `open`)
3. C functions (e.g. `fopen`)

`man printf` returns the first match found, but you don't want information on the `printf` command-line utility; you want information on the `printf` C function. As such, you should be using

```sh
man 3 printf
```